# Show that $(P \rightarrow \lnot R) \lor (P \rightarrow Q)$

Tags: logic

I'm having a lot of trouble proving that $(P \rightarrow \lnot R) \lor (P \rightarrow Q)$ is logically equivalent to $(P\land R) \rightarrow Q.$

I'm very new to this course, and unsure of what to do. Can anyone correct/guide/explain to me, please. This is what I've come up with. Thanks for your help.

1. $(p \rightarrow \lnot r) \lor (p \rightarrow q)$
2. $(\lnot p \lor \lnot r) \lor (\lnot p \lor q)$  [Implication]
3. $\lnot(p \land r) \lor (\lnot p \lor q)$   [De Morgan's]

I don't know what next. I'm thinking Distribution?

Comment: Have you tried building a truth table for these statement? That's where I would start. It will make the rest of the problem more intuitive.

Comment: From (2) you get, by commutative and associate laws for $\lor,$ and because $(\lnot p)\lor (\lnot p)$  is equivalent to $\lnot p,$ that 2. is equivalent to $$(\lnot p \lor \lnot r)\lor q.$$

Comment: Would natural deduction be an option?

Comment: In that case for "$\Rightarrow$": We have $(P \rightarrow \lnot R) \lor (P \rightarrow Q)$.  Assume $P\land Q\land\lnot Q$, from which $P$, $R$ and $P\land\lnot Q$, that is $\lnot(P\rightarrow Q)$ follow.  From the latter we know that we must have $P\rightarrow R$ and as we know $P$, we can follow $\lnot R$. But that together with $R$ is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks. I do not see natural deduction in the unit book, so probably not an option.

Answer (score 1):

One way of looking at it:
\begin{align*}
(P\to\neg R)\lor(P\to Q)
&\equiv (\neg P\lor\neg R)\lor(\neg P\lor Q)\\[0.5em]
&\equiv \neg P \lor\neg R\lor Q \\[0.5em]
&\equiv (\neg P\lor\neg R)\lor Q\\[0.5em]
&\equiv \neg(P\land R)\lor Q\\[0.5em]
&\equiv (P\land R)\to Q
\end{align*}
Can you see what was used/done during each step?

Comment: (¬P∨¬R)∨(¬P∨Q) [implication]; ¬P∨¬R∨Q [Going by a previous comment, is it commutative? ¬P v ¬P is the same as ¬P]. (¬P∨¬R)∨Q [I'm thinking associative, because they are all disjunctions]. ¬(P∧R)∨Q [DeMorgan's]. From this, I don't understand how it leads to the equivalence of (P∧R)→Q

Comment: @user650090 See [material implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)) for $p\to q\equiv\neg p\lor q$ and [double negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation) for $\neg\neg p\equiv p$. Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what next.

Good work recognising that de Morgan's will be useful, but always keep your eye on the *entire* goal.

Take a step back.   You should have used **association** at step 3.   After all, you will want something in the form of $\neg X\vee q$ so you may obtain $X\to q$.   Thus you need to isolate the $q$, and *then* do *something* about that extra $\neg p$, *before* you  apply de Morgan's Laws.

$${1.~(p\to\neg r)\vee(p\to q)
\\2.~ (\neg p\vee\neg r)\vee(\neg p\vee q)
\\3.~ ((\neg p\vee\neg r)\vee \neg p)\vee q
\\\vdots
\\~~~(\neg p\vee\neg r)\vee q
\\~~~\neg (p\wedge r)\vee q\\~~~(p\wedge r)\to q}$$

Answer (score 0):

How can $(P \to \lnot R) \lor (P \to Q)$ be made false?

Only if both terms of the "or" are, so iff $P \to \lnot R$ and $ P \to Q$ are false, and this happens only if $P$ is true and $R$ is true (so $\lnot R$ is false) and $Q$ is false.

How can $(P \land R) \to Q$ be false? Iff if $Q$ is false and $P \land R$ is true, so $P$ and $R$ are true and $Q$ is false.

So both statements are false exactly under the same truth assignments. Hence they are equivalent.